# Java and CORBA in ubuntu

Tags: java, corba

I'm a newbie in java programming. I want to do simple CORBA programming in java in ubuntu. How can I set the environment for java programming with CORBA in ubuntu

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The only Ubuntu specific stuff you need to do is to install Java.  After that, the setup is all described in the Oracle documentation for CORBA with Java.